# counting only one of the values ​in another column of rows with certain columns being equal to each other

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have a dataframe. It shows the page journeys of the users. The columns are; user-id, created_at, action, target. The variable I want to get in target has more than one name and I want to reach the number of them. But these should count only one of the targets that both mean the same thing. Count only one of two different target values ​​for rows containing the same user_id, action, created_at

[image]

For example, if the target value of rows with the same user-id, created-at, action value contains either of these two values, count that row only once. my output should be 2 in the data in the photo

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please share the data as a code (preferably) or text. No Images. here are stackoverflow guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example   ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
df=df.drop_duplicates().groupby('user_id').agg({'user_id':'count'})
```